# Grid is flying around on the responsive part

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am struggling a lot with the responsive part of a page.

When I scale down to around 991 px, the book, and the headline text is flying around. Originally I used `sm-hidden` and `sm-visible`, because I would like that the text headline came first, and afterwords the picture of the book.

But how can I solve this? I am starting to run low on ideas how to make it fit, so the book is not going under the background picture when I reach around the 991 px. I would like that the headline and book img stayed inside the background picture.

I hope somebody can through the developer console see what is wrong here. My code until now looks like this:

```
<div class="background-image" @Html.Raw(topImageStyling)>
            <div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 img logo img-responsive">
                            <a href="www.google.com"><img src="https://www.site.dk/img/inovo-logo-white-small.png"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="book container col-sm-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs col-md-3 col-lg-4">
                    <img src="https://www.site.dk/img/landingpages/.png">
                </div>

                    <div class="container col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-8">

                        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerText))
            {
                if (pageAlias == "Blog")
                {
                                <h1 class="header-xl center">
                                    @Html.Raw(headerText)
                                </h1>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <p class="header-xl">
                                    @Html.Raw(headerText)
                                </p>
                            }
                        }
                        @if (CurrentPage.HasValue("imageTeaserText"))
            {
                            <p class="sub-header center">
                                @Html.Raw(CurrentPage.imageTeaserText)
                            </p>
                        }


                    </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 visible-sm visible-xs">
                    <img src="https://www.site.dk/img/landingpages/g.png">
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 main-content" id="main-content">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                @CurrentPage.GetGridHtml("site")
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Firstly - consider posting all of the code for archiving purposes, so if your website went down the answer provided is still relevant. Secondly - you have a "max height" set on your container, anything inside of this is going to stick to this rule, thirdly - the elements in the container are floating - so the container won't take their height into account. Remove the float from the book container and remove the max-height, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: You should also work on how much code you're writing, because there are a lot of elements and classes you don't need or are overridden by other classes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is just that I am sitting with around 4000 css lines, and it is a little hard to keep track of all the lines. So I hopped we didnt have to do that, when the developer tools is here. I look at the page now. I cannot see a max-height on the container or the container is floating. Which lines of code do you seee that?

Comment: Absolutly agree user3528269. I just got thrown in on a landingpage, without knowing the page or the site. So they said I could just hardcode as much as possible,

Comment: Thanks for posting code for this question. However, I would generally discourage requests for people to visit your site and do debugging via the developer console, since this will not work after you have fixed it, and we want questions with potential long-term value here. [Read this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/472495) to understand more about this, when you have a moment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I think I might have found the solution to your problem. On line 3044 of your CSS, there is the img element. I simply added the following to your code:

```
img {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: relative;
z-index: 1030;}
```

It works for screen sizes larger than the 960px range and acts up a little from the 760px-440px range. I figured all you have to do now is add a media query for the corresponding viewport widths. To explain the solution is simple. Within CSS all elements that are layered within the HTML document have a z-index that determines there position in the stack. From there, in order to get the z-index to respond, I set the position to relative for that img element. The z-index property only works when the position is set to something other than static which is the default value. I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.